# Web API project fails to load in Visual Studio 2019 - error: 'The method or operation is not implemented'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

I have a ASP.Net Web API project that is failing to load in Visual Studio 2019. When I try to reload the project from the Solution Explorer I get the error:

> The method or operation is not implemented

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a cryptic error message - the actual problem preventing the project from loading was:

In the csproj file for the project,  section, I had

```
<UseIIS>true</UseIIS>
```

and IISUrl pointing to a local site that was not yet set up on IIS, e.g.

```
<IISUrl>http://localhost:12321</IISUrl>
```

where there was no site bound to localhost:12321