# Web API project fails to load in Visual Studio 2019 - error: 'Value does not fall within the expected range'

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2019

I have a WCF Service project that is failing to load in Visual Studio 2019. When I try to reload the project from the Solution Explorer I get the error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is the same as the one I mentioned here:

[Web API project fails to load in Visual Studio 2019 - error: 'The method or operation is not implemented'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968784/web-api-project-fails-to-load-in-visual-studio-2019-error-the-method-or-oper)

With `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` in the proj file, I had to make sure that the `<IISUrl>` value pointed to a virtual directory I had set up on IIS.

Another cryptic error from VS!